# dmatrix vs dataframe in XGBoost

Tags: pandas, dataframe, xgboost

I want to build `xgboost` model. As I understood, I have several opportunity for providing model with input data: I can use `Dmatrix` or `Pandas Dataframe`. I am interested which option is better and why.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.core):

> DMatrix is an internal data structure that is used by XGBoost, which
> is optimized for both memory efficiency and training speed. You can
> construct DMatrix from multiple different sources of data.